# Высоконагруженные проекты: Java vs php

Tags: php, java

Устраиваемся поудобнее. Итак, вопрос сплошь теоретический, и, я надеюсь, он не станет предметом холивара.

Представьте, что в один прекрасный день Вам предлагают возглавить разработку масштабного и очень дорогого проекта — потенциально имеющего все перспективы догнать Facebook или ВКонтакте. Но учитывая некоторые известные нюансы, например, что ФБ транслирует php в высоко оптимизированный код C++, а затем компилирует, — поставлена задача, — выбрать наиболее оптимальный вариант, который сводит к минимуму такого рода костыли над нативным языком или не предусматривает их в принципе; в идеале же, вся серверная логика и примитивная генерация страниц должна быть только на одном ЯП — без каких-либо ухищрений.

В рамках данного предложения для рассмотрения допускаются два языка: Java и php (т.к именно последний используется в вышеперечисленных проектах, а первый, скажем, рекламирует себя в качестве энтерпрайза).

Конечно же все плюсы php в сегменте мелкого сайтостроения (блоги, форумы, etc) нам всем хорошо известны — и оспаривать их мы не подумаем; так давайте же рассматривать только очень тонкие уголки: обговариваем сразу со стороны возможностей извращённо-сложных уникальных решений и хайлоада в целом. Вопросы экономического целесообразия можно опустить на задний план, т.к инвесторы Уоррен Баффет и Билл Гейтс выделили нам, ну скажем, достаточное количество средств, чтобы можно было забыть о проекте и потеряться в другой стране, — но мы не такие, поэтому давайте разведем диванную теоретику. :)

Comment: Ну объяснения, почему php были. А вот за java -- только "рекламирует себя в качестве энтерпрайза". Маловато будет.

Comment: Можно ссылку на php

Comment: @NiceForce, PHP vs Java и реальный highload - действительно чисто "диванная теоретика".

Comment: @NiceForce, так Вас в самом деле интересуют только Java и PHP?

Вопросы организации HighAvailability  кластеров, устройств хранения, сети, балансировки нагрузки, организации БД, бэкапов и т.п. (без чего большие системы не существуют и что вне рамок предложенных языков) не интересны?

Тогда речь может пойти только о преимуществах одного из ЯП над другим в области генерации страниц и, естественно, сопровождении проекта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем и целом, обеспечение поддержки высоких нагрузок достигается не языком программирования, а тем, что называется архитектурное решение. Конечно, языки отличаются некоторыми особенностями. Например Java, в отличии от PHP, имеет встроенную поддержку многопоточности. Но это вовсе не может являться главным определяющим фактором, т.к. многие задачи можно распараллелить и с помощью PHP. Поэтому, по моему мнению, выбор языка должен осуществляться из соображений здравого смысла.

Важно выбирать язык, которым хорошо владеет (или может овладеть) команда.

Не менее важно, наличие сообщества разработчиков, использующих данный язык программирования. Это гарантирует наличие библиотек для решения распространненых задач и поможет в решении возникших проблем. Также это упрощает поиск специалистов на рынке труда.

Третий фактор, стоимость разработки и поддержки вашего решения при условии выбора конкретного языка программирования. Например разработка на C++ часто дороже (с точки зрения потраченных сил и времени), чем на Java или PHP.

Comment: @a_gura оно, конечно, так. Но публикуемые в инете бенчмарки заставляют сомневаться. Например http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/03/preliminary-warp-cross-language-benchmarks

Comment: @alexlz Проглядел по диагонали. Эксперимент не выглядит надежным. Особенно радует список caveats. Сравниваются реализации web-серверов на разных языках. Это могут быть плохие реализации. Кроме того, даже если принять эти измерения за правду, можно достичь одинакового показателя requests-per-second, путем добавления железа или изменения архитекруного решения. Да, это цена, которую придется платить. Но сама разработка стоит дороже.

Comment: @NiceForce Привденный вами бенчмарк имеет косвенное отношение к highload. То, что разные языки имеют разные показатели производительности, очевидно. Хотя здесь было бы правильнее говорить не о языке программирования, а о среде выполнения (например код может быть написан на PHP и откомилирован в машинный). Тем не менее это не сильно мешает достигать устойчивости к высоким нагрузкам.

Comment: @NiceForce Ну, вероятно, и на php можно писать надёжные проекты, но язык тут точно задачу не облегчает.

@a_gura и чем Вас радует список caveats?

Comment: @NiceForce они доросли до состояния, когда performance показатели конкретной среды исполнения стали важны. Когда можно освободить десятки/сотни серверов путем смены языка. В общем им стало выгодно вложиться в разработку ради экономии и у них есть нужные специалисты. Заметьте, они не избавляются бездумно от кода на конкретном языке, они оптимизируют "горячие" подсистемы. Scala вместо Rails - грамотное решение: Scala - многопоточна из коробки, т.к. исполняется в JVM. JVM довольно хорошо известна внутри и ее можно оптимизировать. Ruby разработчикам легче дастся Scala, чем PHP или даже Java.

Comment: @alexlz Я не эксперт, я не мог выбрать web-сервер наиболее представляющий язык и т.п. Вопрос возникает, зачем он проделал всю эту работу, если результат ненадежен?

Comment: @a_gura Ну, Шойман -- не веб-программер, а разработчик веб-фреймворка, ему бенчмарки нужны для оценки своей работы -- что, как, куда дальше двигаться...

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле, ответ как раз стоит искать в экономической составляющей. "Потенциально может догнать" - покажет только время. Поэтому в начале стараются писать на том языке, на котором дешевле. Например, php. Если проект выстреливает - переписывают на что-то другое - Java/C#/другие велосипеды. Правильно сказал товарищ [[@a_gura](/users/1439/a_gura)](/users/1439/a_gura) - и на php можно написать highload, и на джаве слоупочный сайт. Все зависит от профессионализма.

Другая сторона медали - железо стоит сейчас дешевле трудов программиста - если задача решается добавлением одного сервера за $50к, то для Билла Гейтса и ко это вообще не деньги, чем платить программистам, оплачивать отпуск, налоги и больничный.

Ответ на счет того, почему избавляются. Да потому что таких задач, какие стоят у них, у 95% компаний вообще не возникает :) . Фейсбук, Твиттер, Вконтакте. Какие еще? Java живет в банках очень хорошо не потому что она вся такая безопасная и кроссплатформенная, а потому что можно нанять компанию-аутсорсера с большим штатом программистов, и если напортачят - прижать большим долларом. И очень много компонентов сертифицированно. Тоесть, можно отдать разработку в Индию, а потом всех уволить, и теоретически нанять рядом с собой американцев на саппорт, но не 100 человек, а 5.

Так что избавляются, потому что это **конкретная техническая задача**. Выстрелит приложение или не выстрелит - неизвестно. На пхп вроде бы как писать быстрее - я не эксперт в пхп. Но как человек, который работает с джавой - на пхп точно дешевле.

Теперь про языки. НИКОГДА не пишите всё на одном языке, потому что так нужно. Функциональный язык лучше справится с многопоточностью. Скриптовый с тестами. Компилируемый будет более производительный, чем скриптовый.

И последнее. Все мы склонны к преждевременной оптимизации) Но увы, без профилировщика все это пустые слова

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [Vibed](http://vibed.org)
По производительности он обгоняет все существующие сервера. Написан на D.

Comment: Вы таки проверили все существующие сервера?

Comment: А на какой профиль нагрузки расчитан этот сервер? Не может же он быть производительнее в принципе. Производительность - слишком широкая тема, что так просто делать подобные заявления.

Comment: Я никак не могу найти ссылку на тесты, но да, vibed обходил даже ряд узкоспециализированных серверов на Erlang.